# Transform records of a column from int to JSON?

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a column with `int` datatype records. I want to first convert them to `varchar` so I can represent them as JSON inside the table. Is this possible?

**Edit:**
I created a test table so I could explain better what I meant with my question.
This is the query I made:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [test_id], [ToJsonTestValue]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Test]
```

[image]

This is the result from the query. What I wish is to convert the column "ToJsonTestValue" to actual JSON. It is of datatype `int`, but what is intended is to alter that to `varchar` and then represent it as JSON.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Where is your example data? Expected results?

Comment: I have been searching but I only find getting the queries in json format. That is not what I pretend. I atually want to change the data inside the table to json format.

Comment: First write a `select` query that gives you the expected [JSON formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server), then change the query to an `update` statement to save the results. Show us what you already have, some sample input data and the expected output. This will allow us to assist you further.

Comment: But what have you actually tried?

Comment: I got closer with the "FOR JSON AUTO" but it's still not what I expected

Comment: @MiguelFerreira What is the expected JSON content of the `ToJsonTestValue` column for each row after the update?

Comment: I saw your solution but still is not what I expected. Turns out it was much simples than I was thinking, I just need to make a set and an update to the rows. Perhaps I didn't make myself clear in the post.

Comment: @MiguelFerreira That's why the expected output is always important.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Apologies for the misundersanding. Thank you for the help tho.

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer:**

If I understand the question correctly, what you may try is to generate a JSON content for each row using `FOR JSON PATH`. The following basic example is a possible solution to your problem:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
   TestId int,
   ToJsonTestValue int
)
INSERT INTO Test (TestId, ToJsonTestValue)
VALUES
   (2, 1),
   (3, 1),
   (4, 2),
   (5, 3)
```

`ALTER` and `UPDATE` table:

```
ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN ToJsonTestValue varchar(1000)
UPDATE Test 
SET ToJsonTestValue = (SELECT ToJsonTestValue FOR JSON PATH)
```

Result:

```
TestId ToJsonTestValue
--------------------------------
2      [{"ToJsonTestValue":"1"}]
3      [{"ToJsonTestValue":"1"}]
4      [{"ToJsonTestValue":"2"}]
5      [{"ToJsonTestValue":"3"}]
```

**Update:**

Note, that with `FOR JSON` you can't generate a JSON array of scalar values (`[1, 2, 3]`), but you may try an approach using `JSON_MODIFY()` (of course, concatenating strings to build the expected outpur is always an option):

```
ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN ToJsonTestValue varchar(1000)
UPDATE Test 
SET ToJsonTestValue = JSON_MODIFY('[]', 'append $', ToJsonTestValue)
```

Result:

```
TestId ToJsonTestValue
----------------------
2      ["1"]
3      ["1"]
4      ["2"]
5      ["3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I was overthinking on this one. I just needed to make a set and an update like this:

```
  UPDATE  dbo.TestTwo
  SET     ToJsonTestValue = '["' + ToJsonTestValue + '"]'
```

The output is like this:

[image]