# SQL Pattern matching not giving the correct output

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find a certain set of characters in a column from a datatable. I have tried the pattern that seems more logical to me (right below) but it doesn't seem to be doing the job. What I wish to achieve is a pattern where I have something like '["5"]', basically with: square brackets, quotation marks, any integer number, quotation marks, square brackets. The output I am getting is just empty, and I can't seem to undersand why. Besides this, I would like to update the records that do not follow this pattern to follow it. Does anyone have a solution for this?

To give you some context, here is the test table:

[image]

I want to achive only the last three records.
Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT ToJsonTestValue
FROM   Test
WHERE  ToJsonTestValue LIKE '["%"]'
```

and

```
 UPDATE dbo.Test
SET     ToJsonTestValue = '["'+ToJsonTestValue+'"]'
WHERE ToJsonTestValue LIKE '#';
```

Comment: Square brackets need special processing... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Can your integer value exceed single digits e.g. `["937"]`?

Comment: If this question is connected with your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64757803/transform-records-of-a-column-from-int-to-json), `WHERE ISJSON(ToJsonTestValue) = 0` is also an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problem here. Firstly you have the square brackets, which needs escaping. Then you also use `%` which is a multi character wildcard, however, it appears that you want a single character. It also appears that that character can only be an integer, so you might want to be more specific. Either of these should give you the result you want:

```sql
--Using single character wildcard:
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('["1"]'),('["["1"]"]'))V(S)
WHERE V.S LIKE '[[]"_"[\]]' ESCAPE '\';

--Specifically requiring int:
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('["1"]'),('["["1"]"]'))V(S)
WHERE V.S LIKE '[[]"[0-9]"[\]]' ESCAPE '\';
```

Comment: Yep that will do the trick! Also, is it possible to also update the remaining records? I mean, instead of just selecting them, the ones who do not follow the intended pattern be updated to follow it?

Comment: You can use that `WHERE` in an `UPDATE`, yes @MiguelFerreira . A `WHERE` doesn't care what type of statement it's in; `SELECT`,`DELETE`, `UPDATE`, etc.

Comment: What would you do for match any number of digits instead of only [0-9]? It's because I have been trying and not being able to solve this problem, the only way I did was by adding more [0-9] (with the "*" I wasn't able to), could you provide me an answer?

Comment: That's a new question at this stage, @MiguelFerreira . Moving the goal posts after getting an answer is frowned upon. Just make sure you reference this question and show your new attempts.