# Index matching patter to any digit

Tags: sql-server

Having in account my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770859/sql-pattern-matching-not-giving-the-correct-output), another problem emerged: I also need to find a pattern for any number, with no limit of digits. I also made some changes: I now have a test table with a column containing only numbers and what I intend to do is to those records who do not match the pattern in the previous question, I want them to follow it again, but including numbers with more than one digit.

Just to provide more context, this is the initial state of the table:

[image]

What I tried was to simply add the " * ", like below:

```
UPDATE dbo.Test
SET     ToJsonTestValue = '["' + ToJsonTestValue + '"]'
WHERE ToJsonTestValue NOT LIKE '[[]"[0-9]*"[\]]' ESCAPE '\';
```

and at a first glance it seemed ok, in the first execution of the query, it just added the pattern I wanted. But when I executed the query a second time, in order to verify that those who already had the pattern would be ignored, the result was this:

[image]

I also tried without the " * ", which works fine but then again, it wont cover all cases (numbers with more than one digit). Without the " * " makes the one digit numbers with the pattern be ignored, which was good, but not sufficient for the task.
This being said, is there a way to solve this stress? Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support the `*` operator; it use very basic patten matching not Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Test table ( test_id int, ToJsonTestValue varchar(255) );
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 43, '6' ), ( 44, '7' ), ( 45, '8' ), ( 46, '888' );

-- Update @Test --
UPDATE @Test
SET
    ToJsonTestValue = '["' + ToJsonTestValue + '"]'
WHERE 
    ToJsonTestValue NOT LIKE '!["%[0-9]%"!]' ESCAPE '!';

-- Update @Test a second time to test 'NOT LIKE' pattern is being matched --
UPDATE @Test
SET
    ToJsonTestValue = '["' + ToJsonTestValue + '"]'
WHERE 
    ToJsonTestValue NOT LIKE '!["%[0-9]%"!]' ESCAPE '!';

-- Show final resultset --
SELECT * FROM @Test ORDER BY test_id;
```

Returns

```
+---------+-----------------+
| test_id | ToJsonTestValue |
+---------+-----------------+
|      43 | ["6"]           |
|      44 | ["7"]           |
|      45 | ["8"]           |
|      46 | ["888"]         |
+---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This works, I have tested it and adapted it to my test cases and it runs smoothly. Thanks a lot for this solution!

Comment: By the way, could you explain the logic behind that pattern?

Comment: The pattern is escaping the two outer left and right brackets (I used `!` as the escape character) so they get used as actual brackets, not a filtering request. The rest is pretty straight-forward in that anything between the quotes/wildcards must have at least one numeric value (doesn't care about length, or if any other characters are involved). If your value was `8A8` you'd still get `["8A8"]` after each update. If your value was simply `A`, this pattern would repeat your initial problem `["["A"]"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work; it works for the examples but I have concerns we'll get a different one again.

You need to use an extra `LIKE` (specifically a `NOT LIKE`) and instead check to ensure that there are no other characters other than `0-9` between the brackets (`[]`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('["1"]'),('["["1"]"]'),('["12"]'))V(S)
WHERE V.S LIKE '[[]"%"[\]]' ESCAPE '\'
  AND V.S NOT LIKE '[[]"%[^0-9]%"[\]]' ESCAPE '\';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have tried it and adapt it but still a no go, it still puts the pattern in the table records when I try to update it. I aprecciate all the help given @Larnu !